change the code of exe in ghidra - need to change 100 lines
I have a Ghidra project with an imported binary file.
I want to change a function . in listing it is 100 code lines - i will no do it via patch instruction (line by line)
Itried to make patch instruction -  is there a  patch that adds many instructions?
or may be i can generate other file - by exporting the current and editing
if this is a way hoe to export? which format to use

if this is about reverse engineering then it might be more relevant on [reverseengineering.se]
